# How to give titles to the different colours of Matlab graphs

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This part of code, will create three different graphs in one frame, and they will all three have different colours. But I don't know which colour corresponds to which `i`.

```
figure('Name','function','NumberTitle','on')
hold all

for i = 1:N 
    plot(input_firingRate(i,:),output_firingRate(i,:))
    ax = gca;
    ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
    ax.YAxisLocation = 'origin';       
end
```

Is there any way to have within the frame a title-like way to distinct between different results and colours? For example:

```
Test i = 1 : 'r'
Test i = 2 : 'g'
Test i = 3 : 'b'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the label for each plot to a cell array, and then pass the cell array to a single call to `legend` after the loop:

```matlab
N = 3;
figure('Name','function','NumberTitle','on')
hold all
titles = cell(N,1);
for i = 1:N 
    plot(1:100,randn(1,100))
    titles{i} = ['line ', num2str(i)];
end
legend(titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the legend function. There are some good examples on its [doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html).

Comment: sure, but I need it to be within the `for` loop. So, i tried: `legend('i', num2str(i))` in the loop but it still doesn't work. I would appreciate it if you had any advice

Comment: No, the call to legend doesn't go in the loop. If you look at the examples on that doc page, the one about 'DisplayName' property is probably the simplest for this case. You just add that to each call to plot and do `legend show` at the end.